# Dynamically create properties on an object without using `Proxy`

Tags: javascript, typescript, immutable.js

I know you can dynamically create properties using the ES2015 `Proxy` API:

```js
const someObject = {
  foo: 'bar',
  some: 'thing',
};

const proxy = new Proxy(someObject, {
  get: (target, prop) => {
    if (target[prop] === undefined) {
      target.prop = `newly added ${prop}`;
      return target.prop;
    }
    return target.prop;
  }
});

proxy.one;

console.log(someObject);
```

Can I do this without the unpolyfillable Proxy?

---

> What is your actual problem? – Bergi

I'm trying create a function that takes a selector function that selects a property from a bigger object and transforms that into an array of strings of the properties:

```
function getNestedPath<T, S>(selector: (t: T) => S): string[] {
  // ...
}

const obj = {
  nested: {
    a: 'something',
  }
};

getNestedPath($ => $.nested.a); // ['nested', 'a']
```

---

Even more context:

I'm using immutable.js and there is an `setIn` and `updateIn` methods that take in an array of strings which are the properties of the nested object you want to set or update.

Here's their example:

```
const { Map } = require('immutable@4.0.0-rc.9')
const originalMap = Map({
  subObject: Map({
    subKey: 'subvalue',
    subSubObject: Map({
      subSubKey: 'subSubValue'
    })
  })
})

const newMap = originalMap.setIn(['subObject', 'subKey'], 'ha ha!')
// Map {
//   "subObject": Map {
//     "subKey": "ha ha!",
//     "subSubObject": Map { "subSubKey": "subSubValue" }
//   }
// }

const newerMap = originalMap.setIn(
  ['subObject', 'subSubObject', 'subSubKey'],
  'ha ha ha!'
)
// Map {
//   "subObject": Map {
//     "subKey": "subvalue",
//     "subSubObject": Map { "subSubKey": "ha ha ha!" }
//   }
// }
```

What I want to do is see if I can change the API to be...

```
updateIn<S>(selector: ($: this) => S, updater: (s: S | undefined) => S): this;
```

...mainly because that API works better with typescript typings. To do that, I thought I could use something like `Proxy` to transform the selector function: `($: T) => S` to an array of strings `string[]`.

```
const originalMap = Map({
  subObject: Map({
    subKey: 'subvalue',
    subSubObject: Map({
      subSubKey: 'subSubValue'
    })
  })
})

// how this API would look
originalMap.updateNested(
  $ => $.subObject.subSubObject,
  subSubObject => subSubObject.set('subSubKey', 'new value')
)
```

---

[Here is a playground with the concept](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20ProxyObj%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20__nextProxy__%3A%20ProxyObj%20%7C%20undefined%2C%0D%0A%20%20__propUsed__%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20traverse(s%3A%20ProxyObj)%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20nextProxy%20%3D%20s.__nextProxy__%3B%0D%0A%20%20const%20nextProps%20%3D%20(%2F*if*%2F%20nextProxy%20%3F%20traverse(nextProxy)%20%3A%20%5B%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20const%20prop%20%3D%20s.__propUsed__%3B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(!prop)%20%7B%20return%20%5B%5D%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20return%20%5Bprop%2C%20...nextProps%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20createProxy()%3A%20any%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20new%20Proxy(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20__propUsed__%3A%20undefined%20as%20string%20%7C%20undefined%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20__nextProxy__%3A%20undefined%20as%20any%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20get%3A%20(target%2C%20prop)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(prop%20%3D%3D%3D%20'__nextProxy__')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(target.__nextProxy__)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20target.__nextProxy__%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(prop%20%3D%3D%3D%20'__propUsed__')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20target.__propUsed__%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(prop%20%3D%3D%3D%20'get')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(p%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target.__propUsed__%20%3D%20p%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20newProxy%20%3D%20createProxy()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target.__nextProxy__%20%3D%20newProxy%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20newProxy%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target.__propUsed__%20%3D%20prop.toString()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20newProxy%20%3D%20createProxy()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target.__nextProxy__%20%3D%20newProxy%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20newProxy%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20function%20selectorToPath%3CT%2C%20S%3E(selector%3A%20(t%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20S)%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20proxy%20%3D%20createProxy()%3B%0D%0A%20%20selector(proxy)%3B%0D%0A%20%20return%20traverse(proxy)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20SomeClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%20%3D%20'bar'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20nested%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20one%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20two%3A%20'foo'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20updateIn%3CS%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20selector%3A%20(%24%3A%20this)%20%3D%3E%20S%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20update%3A%20(s%3A%20S)%20%3D%3E%20S%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20blah%20blah%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20pretend%20this%20is%20immutable.js%0D%0Aconst%20record%20%3D%20new%20SomeClass()%3B%0D%0Arecord.updateIn(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20intellisense%20for%20things%20that%20don't%20exist%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%24%20%3D%3E%20%24.nested%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20s%20%3D%3E%20s%0D%0A)%3B%0D%0A). See line 77

Comment: Can do what? Do you know the name `one` beforehand?

Comment: What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: @Bergi no I don't know the name of `one` beforehand. I'll update the answer with some context.

Comment: Then no, you need a proxy. Or not use object properties for your dynamically created values.

Comment: @Bergi I updated my answer with context, but you really already answered the question I asked to begin with. If you post an answer with "Then no, you need a proxy.", I'll accept it. I'll gladly take any ideas though.

Comment: Ok, so the property names are not totally arbitrary, they're actually from TypeScript interfaces. Of those could be reified to be available at runtime, you could possibly do something useful. I'm not well-versed in TypeScript though to judge its metaprogramming capabilities.

Comment: @Berg yup, that the idea. It's interesting at least. I'm not sure I would use it in production but it's fun to experiment with.

I added link at the end of the question in a typescript playground where intellisense is enabled. Add a `.` to line 77